# Modify MVCScaffolding t4 template for DB First

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am looking to use MvcScaffolding for a website that I already have a database for.

I am using the repository switch when scaffolding to create a repository per entity and then editing the file to use the entities rather than the MvcScaffolding context, obviously if I re generate the files then this change will be overwritten and I will have to fix all 80+ repositories!

So I have created a custom repository template using

```
Scaffold CustomTemplate repository repository
```

which I am looking to edit so that the repositories are generated correctly. I know I need to edit this line

```
<#= contextName #> context = new <#= contextName #>();
```

but I can't find which variable I should replace `contextName` with.

I know I could easily hard code the model name in the repository file which I am about to do but wondered if there is a better way to do this?

The reason for wanting a way to do it programmatically is for scenarios where more than 1 EF model is used in a project and scaffolding is used for both.

Thanks

OneShot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `DbContextType` param for the scaffolders -

> -DbContextType : Specify the name of the database context class that
>   should be generated or updated. By default, we use the name
>   Context, e.g., SoccerSiteContext.

Could you set that to be the name of the relevant model and avoid changing the template?

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I'd missed that when I'd already been through Steve Sanderson's blog! :-)